# Show image from local file in Outlook signature

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I am trying to send Outlook email from MS Access VBA. I include a signature file.

However, the image in the signature cannot be shown. The signature file is located in %appdata%Microsoft/Signature folder.

How can I make the sending email show the image?

And here is the content of the folder.
[image]

Here is the code.

```vb
Private Sub btn_ToOutlook_Click()
    
    Dim bStarted As Boolean
    Dim oOutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim oItem As Outlook.MailItem
    'On Error Resume Next
    
    'update workflow status to Renewal Table
    'MsgBox frmPrevious.WorkflowName
    
    'see if Outlook is running and if so turn your attention there
    Set oOutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then 'Outlook isn't running
       'So fire it up
       Set oOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
       bStarted = True
    End If
    
    ' Change only Mysig.htm to the name of your signature
    SigString = Environ("appdata") & _
                "\Microsoft\Signatures\Peter Hon.htm"

    If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
        Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)
    Else
        Signature = ""
    End If
    
    'Open a new e-mail message
    Set oItem = oOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With oItem 'and add the detail to it
       .To = "eddie@abc.com"  'send to this address
       .CC = "grace@abc.com"
       .Subject = "[SW Maintenance Renewal] Request for Credit Check" + " " + Format(Date, "mmm yyyy") 'This is the message subject
       .HTMLBody = frmPrevious.EmailContent & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Signature
       .Display
    End With
    If bStarted Then 'If the macro started Outlook, stop it again.
       oOutlookApp.Quit
    End If
    
    'Clean up
    Set oItem = Nothing
    Set oOutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set frmPrevious = Screen.ActiveForm
    Set webControl = Me.wb.Object
    With webControl
    End With
    'Me.TimerInterval = 300
    Sleep (5000)
    ShowHtml
End Sub


Private Sub ShowHtml()
    Set webControl = Me.wb.Object
    With webControl
        .Document.Write frmPrevious.EmailContent
    End With
End Sub

Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
'Dick Kusleika
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetBoiler = ts.readall
    ts.Close
End Function
```

And here is the image
[image]

Comment: It appears the contents of the html file have been added to the message, but apparently there's an issue with the source of the images within the signature file. Can you see the images if you open the html file directly?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, do not concatenate HTML strings - concatenating two well-formed HTML documents won't produce a valid HTML document. The two must be merged.

By default, `img` tags in HTML signatures reference image files using a relative (to the Signatures folder) path. When you create HTML body, the file path is left as is. It is your responsibility to retrieve images from the signature, add image files as attachments, set `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` MAPI property, and modify the image source in the img tag to reference the image by the cid rather than path. Ditto for the signature styles.

If you want to programmatically insert a signature, [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) exposes [RDOSignature](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosignature.htm) object which implements `ApplyTo` method (it handles the signature image files and merges HTML styles appropriately).

Also keep in mind that Outlook inserts a signature automatically when a message is displayed as long as the message body is not modified prior to the call. Call `MailItem.Display` first (Outlook will insert a signature at that point), then append your own text - find the position of the `"<body"` string in `HTMLBody` property, look for the next `">"` (to take care of the body tags with attributes), and insert your HTML after that `">"`.

Answer (score 0):

We store the images externally, at **imgur** (free), and call them by their full URL like this:

```
<p style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/HbdRTBD.gif" alt="Cactus Data ApS" title="Cactus Data ApS" /><br>
</p>
```

Comment: Cannot use images stored in local folder? Because outlook signature html file is saved in local folder and it is unlikely to change the image link from locally to external.

Comment: No. How should the receivers be able to reach them? Alternatively, the image will have to be embedded in the Mime message, but that will/may bloat the message quite a lot.